# Get all values from multiselet and insert it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

How can I assign all selectedMeasures into my "answers"

There is selectedMeasures

```
get selectedMeasures() {
    const items = this.measureItems.filter((item: any) => item.selected);
    return items.length ? JSON.stringify(items.map(item => ({value: item.value}))) : '';
  }
```

This is console.log selectedMeasures

```
console.log('selectedMeasures: '+ this.selectedMeasures);
```

output:

> selectedMeasures: [{"value":"Average"},{"value":"Last"}]

I got exported interface **answers.ts**

```
export interface Answers {
    id?: number;
    f01: string;
    f02: string;
    cb1: string;
}
```

and in my main .ts file

```
answers: Answers = {
    id: undefined,
    f01: '',
    f02: '',
    cb1: this.selectedMeasures
  };
```

but I have nothing in cb1

f01,f02 works fine I am using it like this:

```
<input id="f01" [(ngModel)]="answers.f01" type="text" class="form-control cc-exp">
```

and I did the same in my multiselect

```
<ngx-dropdown-list [items]="measureItems" id="cb1" [(ngModel)]="answers.cb1" [multiSelection]="true" [placeHolder]="'Measures'"></ngx-dropdown-list>
```

How Can I put my output into **cb1**?

Comment: can you create this issue in stackblitz.com?. It may easy to find out your issue.

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy this is what Sapikelio said but I do not got only one value.. I want all of them :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `[(ngModel)]` with `[(selectedValue)]` like this.

```
<ngx-dropdown-list [items]="measureItems" id="cb1" [(selectedValue)]="answers.cb1" [multiSelection]="true" [placeHolder]="'Measures'"></ngx-dropdown-list>
```

Comment: Now cb1 got only one value ( the latest one) no all of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectionchange in ngx-dropdownlist.

`(selectionChange)="onChange($event)"`

In that onChangeEvent you can assign selected values to your variable like `answers.cb1`

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6l5uss?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html